# Routing problem: realURL create some wrong links to news-item with direction via page

Tags: realurl, tt-news

Since we upgraded Typo3 from 8.7.19 to 8.7.32 we find several links to tt_news prefixed with one special page: instead of "/news/xxx" we get "/voorbeeldbrieven/loonbeslag/news/xxx".
"Voorbeeldbrieven/loonbeslag" is an existing page. It has no News-plugin or any reference to news on it.
Strangely enough it only happens with this specific page. Most of the time the redirection is correct.

I have no idea where to look. There is also no relation to be found with Apache's access-log in time or query.

Any help?